# MS Access Connection to JDBC in Java 8

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, java-8

Before Java 8, I have been using the following driver and connection string to connect to an MS Access Database.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DBName");
```

Today, I tried to run my application which uses the above code, using JDK 8 and got a ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

This is apparent since the JDBC-ODBC Driver has been removed in JDK 8.

So, I was wondering what other ways can we connect to an MS Access Database with Java 8 using the JDBC functionality.

Comment: Thanx Gord. Exactly what i was looking for! :)